# Shell Script for File name conversion in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, filenames

I am pretty new to Unix and have little exposure to shell script. I need to come up with a script that converts the file names from certain string values to special characters. This needs to be run in such a way all files under sub-directories also gets renamed.

For Example:

From: abc(GE)xyz(PR).txt changes 
To: abc>xyz%.txt

I m ok to set if condition for all required special characters, but im not sure what options to pass and how to do it for all sub-directories.

Thanks,
Jeel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
# given a filename, execute any desired replacements.
update_name() {
  local orig_name_var=$1
  local dest_name_var=$2
  local orig_name=${!orig_name_var}
  local new_name="$orig_name"

  new_name=${new_name//(GE)/">"}
  new_name=${new_name//(PR)/"%"} # repeat for additional substitutions

  printf -v "$dest_name_var" "$new_name"
}

while IFS= read -r -d '' orig_name; do
  update_name orig_name new_name
  [[ $orig_name = $new_name ]] && continue

  if ! [[ -e $orig_name ]]; then
    orig_dirname=${orig_name%/*}
    orig_basename=${orig_name##*/}
    update_name orig_dirname new_dirname
    if [[ -e $new_dirname/$orig_basename ]]; then
      # we already renamed the directory this file is in
      orig_name=$new_dirname/$orig_basename
    fi
  fi
  mv -- "$orig_name" "$new_name"
done < <(find . '(' -name '*(GE)*' -o -name '*(PR)*' ')' -print0)
```